# How to handle large systematic missing data in time series?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, missing-data, data-imputation

I have this time series, where on the weekends, the dependent variable values are missing.

It's only a time series, I do not have any exogenous regressors/features. The dependent variable value is an industry metric. Currently, on Saturdays and Sundays, no real values are recorded, officially, they perform Last Observation Carried Forward (LOCF) for Saturdays and Sundays (That is, Friday's value is used for Saturday and Sunday).

This is very systematic and almost 30% of the data is LOCF and on those specific dates. I suspect that this is ruining my time series forecasting using ARIMA.

What should I do? I have thought about using multiple imputation, performing random forest regression on the valid data and fill in those 30%/performing KNN regression for the same. (given that random forest and KNN are very related)

I haven't encountered other people having this specific issue and implementing a specific solution.